# Is there any available option in Highcharts about displaying of label fully?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Hi my goal is to display fully the label from left (-100%) and right (100.2%), Currently it is truncated when the percentage is above or equal to three digit.

I want to fix this using HighCharts properties. any help please.

[image]

Comment: Try to increase [spacingRight](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingRight) / [marginRight parameters](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginRight) in chart options. If not solves issue, recreate demo as live example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
labels: { 
    align: 'left',  
    style: { 
        textOverflow:'none', 
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap' 
    } 
 }
```